# every absolutely convergence in interval of convergence is uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that if
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x)$$
 is absolutely convergence in interval of convergence then its uniformly convergence

I know that if the series of function absolutely convergence then its convergent
easy to prove by Cauchy.
but what is the effect of interval of convergent to make the series uniformly convergence not only point wise??

Comment: are the functions continuous?

Comment: You want to mean $f_n (x) $

Comment: fn (x) series of functions

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing... Try 
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} g_n $$
on $[0,1]$ with 
$$ g_n:= x^{n}-x^{n+1}  \ (\geq 0, \forall x\in [0,1])$$

Indeed, 
$$\sum_{n= 1}^N g_n(x)=  1-x^{N+1} \underset{N\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow g(x) $$
with $g(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1)$ and $g(1)=0$.

Since $g_n$ is positive, the convergence is absolute but **cannot be uniform** since if it were, the limit would be continuous.

Comment: thanks, but is there any other condition to make it true??

Comment: @user535112 I don't think so... and I don't see why it should be, since, basically, if the functions $f_n$ are positive, the absolute convergence of  $\sum f_n$ is nothing more than the regular pointwise convergence...

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n $$ is absolutely convergent at $(-1,1) $ but not uniformly.

$$S (x)-S_n (x)=\frac{x^n}{1-x} $$

is not bounded.

Comment: is S(x)=1/(1-x) and Sn(x)=x^n ?!!

Comment: @user535112 $$S_n (x)=\frac {1-x^n}{1-x} $$